# Bash Shell no printed output after checking a -lt condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to test if Variable X is less than 50, if yes then print it (echo it), but I am getting no output!

```bash
X=1
if [$X -lt 50]
then 
    echo $X
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following :

```
X=1
if [ "$X" -lt 50 ]
then 
    echo $X
fi
```

Whitespace matters in bash.